I can't find information on adding manifest to Power Pages
I have created a PWA using Power Pages. When I try to build a package using PWABuilder, I get the message that a manifest was not found in the application.
I have used PWABuilder to edit the manifest.
How do I upload the Manifest into Power Pages so that PWABuilder can find and use it?
